# Autorun Script Now Automatically Shuts Down

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, gps

So I'm using Raspbian to create a mobile GPS tracker. I wanted it to log data then safely shut down the pi when I was done. I figured I could just plug in my mini keyboard when I was done and click control-c to stop it.
Well, everything worked according to plan, but I didn't have the forethought about when I'm done with my tests and need to use my pi again/get the data off of it.
I chose to bypass the login and directly start running the script. So when I connected my pi to a display, I see it running the script as it's supposed to. The last line of the script says that on keyboard interrupt, run the shutdown -h now command through the os module.
So, what I've done to myself is have it run a program that I can only get out of with keyboard interrupt and then when I use that automatically shut down the pi. So I can't stop this loop of running the script and shutting down to get back to normal operating conditions.

Any advice is appreciated.

The process I used to run on startup is from this webpage:
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/02/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-raspberry-pi-boot/

Comment: I was able to get to a command line by changing the cmdline.txt to init=/bin/sh/ and I can get to my bad python file but it says its read-only file system even though I typed sudo.

Comment: Put cmdline.txt back to normal and boot the Pi.  Press ctrl+alt+f1 to get a login window, login, edit your script, save, and reboot.

Comment: I figured out how to fix it. On the cmdline.txt file i need to put rw before bootwait. That allows me to write. Then I can edit the broken python file. After fixing the python file to be totally commented out, I put cmdline.txt back to normal and use the comp like I would otherwise.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to do a self answer so that the solution is clear to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by first stopping my script from running.

I held shift and went into the noobs setup. From there you can edit cmdline.txt

In cmdline.txt I put rw in front of rootwait and added init=/bin/sh/

Then I restarted the Pi. This brought me to the command line at start instead of my python script running.

I typed sudo nano /home/pi/myfilename.py

I then edited the python file so the entire thing is commented out (i.e. put ''' at the front and end''')

Restarted again and removed the stuff I had added to cmdline.txt earlier and it worked just as good as it was before.