# Bad config file for motion, starting as a service, poweroff my raspberry at each boot

Tags: pi-zero, motion

I try to use Motion on a Raspberry pi zero.
worked fine, but using webcontrol I wanted to stop the raspberry when I motion was ended.
I added this line to my motion.conf :

on_event_end /usr/sbin/poweroff

I tought than on_event_end was triggered by exit from motion.

In fact, each time I start my Raspberry, Motion starts and the on_event_end immediatly triggers the poweroff.
I don't have time to open a ssh session and try to edit the file.

I tried to add init=/bin/bash in the cmdline.txt, adding a monitor and a keyboard, but the Pi starts with all files en read only mode, so I can't correct my config file.

Is there a solution, and in the worst case, is it possible to restart the Raspberry in its initial state (without any user files)

Thanks a lot for any help

*** I found a solution :
starting pizero with the standard cmmdline.txt and a keyboard and screen, I had time enough to rename the motion.conf file before Motion started.
Motion doesn't start because there whre no motion.conf, so I had time enough to remove the erroneous line.
Tricky, as my AZERTY keyboard was used as QWERTY

Comment: See [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136300/how-to-change-files-on-raspberry-pi-without-starting-it-up/136301#136301) for a possible solution.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside the question. You can answer your own question by clicking on the **Answer your own question** button below. Once you answer your question, please accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark  next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others find the correct answer.