# I have auto run a python program in raspberry pi and now iam not able to stop the autorun

Tags: raspbian

I included the program location in nano /etc/profile and in nano /etc/rc.local. even if I remove it form those it is not terminating the autorun

Comment: Try moving or renaming the program.  The thing that is running it might try to alert you in some way.

Comment: Does this question solve your problem? [How to change files on raspberry pi without starting it up?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136300/how-to-change-files-on-raspberry-pi-without-starting-it-up)